# Using a year-field on the x-axis of a lineChart in dc.js

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I am having troubles to implement a data parser using `d3`.
I have a field in my `csv`dataset that looks like this:

```
.., year, ..

.., 1987, ..
.., 1988, ..
.., 1989, ..
.., 1990, ..
```

I would like to use this year dimension on a `x-axis` of a `dc.lineChart`.
The following is my implementation using `crossfilter.js`

```
var ndx = crossfilter(data);    
var yearDim  = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.year});
```

At the moment I am using the following solution, which as you can see does not achieve the wanted result:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
   d.year = parseInt(d.year);
});
...
...
yearChart
   .width(870)
   .height(500)
   .dimension(yearDim)
   .group(numberPerYear)
   .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([1987,2015]))
   .elasticY(true)
   .controlsUseVisibility(true)
   .yAxis().ticks(5);
```

However, this results in having `integer` on the x-axis. I tried also to create a parser for the date, but I do not know how to pass the parameter after and also I am not sure whether this is the right solution, since the function I found online are deprecated (v.3).

```
  var dateFormatSpecifier = '/%Y';
  var dateFormat = d3.timeFormat(dateFormatSpecifier);
  var dateFormatParser = d3.timeParse(dateFormatSpecifier);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using [`d3.scaleTime()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#scaleTime) instead of `d3.scaleLinear()`. You can simply set the domain to exactly 00:00 for the start and end dates for the domain:

```
.x(d3.scaleTime().domain([
    new Date("January 1, 1987 00:00:00"),
    new Date("January 1, 2015 00:00:00")
]));
```

Remember to transform the `d.year` into a Date object:

```
var yearDim  = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return new Date(d.year); });
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there an easy way to show a different range label at the top of my chart? For example, I have this: _range: [01/29/1991 -> 01/07/1999]_ and I would like to show something like _range: [1991 -> 1999]_. Is not a big problem, I am aware of that, but I was wondering if you know a quick way to implement it.

Comment: You can override (assign to) [dc.dateFormat](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.html#dateFormat).